# Why using Fokl as an enzyme in the zinc finger nuclease method?

Tags: restriction-enzymes

I started reading about CRISPR, and then about older methods of gene editing. I recently learnt about zinc finger nucleases, where Fokl (a restriction enzyme without specificity) gets specificity, thanks to the zinc finger domains, and can do one stranded breaks. So my question is, why do we need an enzyme which only cuts on one side of the DNA? Is there no other restriction enzyme which has no specificity and can cut on both sides of the DNA? I tried to research on my own, for example in papers, where the zinc finger nucleases method is described like in “Genome Engineering With Zinc-Finger Nucleases”, but I didn’t find the answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes, there are restriction enzymes that induce double stranded breaks. In fact, unmodified FokI is a  restriction endonuclease (indicating it creates double-stranded breaks) ¹. Modified domains of FokI can turn it into a nickase (single-stranded breaks) ².

The reason these nicks are desired is because the repair of single-stranded breaks (SSBs) promotes different DNA repair pathways, I quote ²:

> "Here, we demonstrate that site-specific DNA-nicking enzymes (nickases)—constructed by engineering the FokI nuclease domain of ZFNs—can induce SSBs in the genome, whose repair via highly accurate HR gives rise to targeted genome modifications. Importantly, SSBs are not repaired by error-prone NHEJ, and, therefore, do not give rise to indels at both on-target and off-target sites. Thus, SSB-inducing zinc finger (ZF) nickases could serve as highly specific mutagens with no or little off-target effects."

Nicks can be repaired via the less error-prone Homology Directed Repair (HDR) pathway. It is important to note that (in humans) the HDR pathway may be different between double- and single-stranded breaks ³.

1. https://www.neb.com/en-gb/products/r0109-foki#Product%20Information | 2024/02/12
2. Kim, Eunji, et al. "Precision genome engineering with programmable DNA-nicking enzymes." Genome research 22.7 (2012): 1327-1333.
3. Davis, Luther, and Nancy Maizels. "Homology-directed repair of DNA nicks via pathways distinct from canonical double-strand break repair." Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences 111.10 (2014): E924-E932.